# ArcMap stops working after installation of add-in

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, c#, error, add-in

I developed an extension for ArcGIS Desktop 10.8.1 using ArcObjects and C#. After a colleague tried to install the Add-In using the ESRI ArcGIS Add-In Installation Utility, his ArcMap could not be started anymore. ArcGIS threw the error "Please wait while we gather information about the error..." and did not react at all. The thing is that I tested the extension on a different PC and it worked perfectly fine (same configuration of ArcGIS applications).

I checked the versions of every ArcGIS application and the .Net Framework version which seem to be suitable. So I checked the error log and found a file that belongs to the start-up sequence after installing the extension. The following snippet shows the results.

```
DEBUG_FLR_EXCEPTION_CODE(80131500) and the ".exr -1" ExceptionCode(e0434352) don't match
MethodDesc:   1f496310
Method Name:  SimpleInjector.dll!Unknown
Class:        1f4a904c
MethodTable:  1f496460
mdToken:      06000238
Module:       1f4945d0
IsJitted:     yes
CodeAddr:     28a04cc0
Transparency: Critical
MethodDesc:   1f4962d4
Method Name:  SimpleInjector.dll!Unknown
Class:        1f4a904c
MethodTable:  1f496460
mdToken:      06000233
Module:       1f4945d0
IsJitted:     yes
CodeAddr:     28a030a0
Transparency: Critical
MethodDesc:   1f4966d8
Method Name:  SimpleInjector.dll!Unknown
Class:        1f4a904c
MethodTable:  1f496460
mdToken:      06000225
Module:       1f4945d0
IsJitted:     yes
CodeAddr:     1f05a788
Transparency: Critical
MethodDesc:   1f03de90
Method Name:  ArcGisPlannerToolbox.dll!Unknown
Class:        36a68b80
MethodTable:  1f03dea4
mdToken:      060000b4
Module:       1f03d690
IsJitted:     yes
CodeAddr:     1f058e18
Transparency: Critical
MethodDesc:   152b15ac
Method Name:  <Module>.CCWButton.InternalOnClick(CCWButton*)
Class:        152a7e40
MethodTable:  152b77cc
mdToken:      060004c3
Module:       0c9417e8
IsJitted:     yes
CodeAddr:     1f058720
Transparency: Safe critical
Failed to request MethodData, not in JIT code range
MethodDesc:   0c94f8c8
Method Name:  <Module>.CCWCommand<ICommand,ESRI::ArcGIS::Desktop::AddIns::Button>.OnClick(CCWCommand<ICommand,ESRI::ArcGIS::Desktop::AddIns::Button>*)
Class:        152a7e40
MethodTable:  152b77cc
mdToken:      0600029b
Module:       0c9417e8
IsJitted:     yes
CodeAddr:     1f056b78
Transparency: Safe critical
KEY_VALUES_STRING: 1
    Key  : Analysis.CPU.mSec
    Value: 387890
    Key  : Analysis.DebugAnalysisManager
    Value: Create
    Key  : Analysis.Elapsed.mSec
    Value: 495852
    Key  : Analysis.Init.CPU.mSec
    Value: 765
    Key  : Analysis.Init.Elapsed.mSec
    Value: 26387
    Key  : Analysis.Memory.CommitPeak.Mb
    Value: 620
    Key  : CLR.BuiltBy
    Value: NET48REL1LAST_C
    Key  : CLR.Engine
    Value: CLR
    Key  : CLR.Version
    Value: 4.8.4300.0
    Key  : Timeline.Process.Start.DeltaSec
    Value: 172
    Key  : WER.Process.Version
    Value: 10.8.1.14362

CONTEXT:  (.ecxr)
eax=001ce608 ebx=00000005 ecx=00000005 edx=00000000 esi=001ce6cc edi=00000001
eip=76aea8b2 esp=001ce608 ebp=001ce664 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz ac po nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000212
KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x62:
76aea8b2 8b4c2454        mov     ecx,dword ptr [esp+54h] ss:002b:001ce65c=301d9cca
Resetting default scope
EXCEPTION_RECORD:  (.exr -1)
ExceptionAddress: 76aea8b2 (KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x00000062)
   ExceptionCode: e0434352 (CLR exception)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000001
NumberParameters: 5
   Parameter[0]: 80131500
   Parameter[1]: 00000000
   Parameter[2]: 00000000
   Parameter[3]: 00000000
   Parameter[4]: 749c0000
PROCESS_NAME:  ArcMap.exe
EXCEPTION_CODE_STR:  80131500
FAULTING_THREAD:  ffffffff
STACK_TEXT:  
00000000 00000000 ArcMap!unknown_function+0x0

STACK_COMMAND:  ** Pseudo Context ** ManagedPseudo ** Value: ffffffff ** ; kb
SYMBOL_NAME:  ArcMap!unknown_function
MODULE_NAME: ArcMap
IMAGE_NAME:  ArcMap.exe
FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  CLR_EXCEPTION_80131500_ArcMap.exe!unknown_function
OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x86
OSNAME:  Windows 8
IMAGE_VERSION:  10.8.1.14362
FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {86425d1f-00f7-f588-2aee-074485e91304}
Followup:     MachineOwner
---------
```

Has somebody encountered a similar problem before and is experinced in solving it?

Comment: check if a referenced DLL is not installed / available on the faulty computer.

Comment: Thank you. I will give it a try.